# My first time with jQuery: Using filters as triggers

Tags: jquery

I am writing my first jQuery command. We have a filter that filters the projects by category. Now we want the display image to change as well. I have already tried a code for this but can't find the error. It works when you switch from one filter to the other, but the display image does not disappear when you deselect the filter. To understand, the filters have a class "is--active" when they are selected and the display image has a combo class for category and an "is--visible" so that it changes from display:none to block. This would be my test page: [Link](https://schmid-wolf-2nd-4c75eb97f43a6158f70c7b6.webflow.io/projekte)

What I have so far:

```
//Reset all
$('.filters-button').on('click', function() {
  $('.is--visible').removeClass('is--visible');
});

// Show Digital
$('#digital').on('click', function() {
  $('.digital').addClass('is--visible');
});

// Reset Image by Active Filter 
$('.is--active').on('click', function() {
  $('.is--visible').removeClass('is--visible');
});
```

Comment: what you wan to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your interest @NegiRox. So, I want that when you click on the filter with for example the ID #digital that the combo class is--visible is added to the thumbnail .digital and when you deselect the filter this class is removed. But it should also be removed when you click on another filter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.